# Get an Edittext value of an listview when click on it's item

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a litview in my code and into each item there is an edittext with a button , So what i want to do is get the edittext's value when press on the button of an listview's item.

I'v tried to get the value by declaring it like this , but it returns null value !

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
LayoutInflater linflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view1 = linflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
final EditText replyfld = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.replyfld);
final Button sendreplybtn = (Button)view1.findViewById(R.id.sendreplybtn);

sendreplybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String thereplyvalue = replyfld.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(MessagesActivity.this, thereplyvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
}
```

What to do please ?

Comment: What returns null? Any exception?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, It returns null value (means returns nothing).

Comment: On which line of your code I mean.

Comment: When I'm using `Toast` to display the string on the screen it shows empty Toast alert !

Comment: So it doesn't null. It is empty, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes my dear, exactly.

Comment: Can you post the view xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code at pastebin.com/HejVn4bb .

Looks like calling replytogglebtn.setFavorite(false,true); (Line:101) in onClickListener before getting text is the problem because setOnFavoriteChangeListener() clears the edittext.

just get text before the setFavorite(false,true);

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it inside your Adapter. Can you past the code of it?

Comment: It's in the Adapter now dear and here is the Adapter's code : https://pastebin.com/HejVn4bb

Comment: It could be that you have more edittext with the sam id.. Like the other user said, please post the xml code.